# Add .ucode driver in Debian installer

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, network-interface

When I install Debian, installer request network connection. But Debian can't found my Ethernet card (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260).

I use non-free [installer](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/)  and try put `.ucode` file in `/firmware/` folder on USB (from [here](http://www.intel.ru/content/www/ru/ru/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html)), but it not work!

I also try renamed `iwlwifi-8000` in iwlwifi-8260, but it also not work.

Big thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

According to [intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) to get the **wifi** working on *Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260* on debian you need a kernel version `> 4.1` , also it is not possible to load the wifi driver during the install because the stable version use the `3.16` kernel version;

Comment: OK. On 4,1+ linux simply add .ucode in /firmware?

Comment: Yes , under `lib/firmware` ; first download the `iso` from here http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/current/ ,then  install your system , connect through Ethernet and install a kernel version from backports

Comment: > connect through Ethernet

Comment: Not work if l put driver in /firmware/

Comment: Installer not see driver file